# Preventing XSS the right way

Tags: utf-8, xss, echo

I know that to prevent XSS, we need to be context aware.

when we do echo $userinput; we need to be aware of the fact that if that input goes into a textbox value, or into textarea value or into a division html area and so on.

I'd like to simplify the echo business so that I can use a single function for most of my echo needs. with that in mind, I put together the following function but I'm not sure, if it's a good idea to rely on it.

Of course, I made some assumptions. 
That is I always use the built in urlencode for urls. And I religiously delimit attributes with either ' or ".

With this in mind, can I use the below safeecho as opposed to the plain echo to prevent XSS?

```
function safeecho($str)
{

    return htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

}
```

One thing I'm not sure is the `<Style>` context. I've seen people talk about the "expressions" issue with stylesheets. I'm not sure how that is dealt with though. But since I do not plan on outputting userinput in the midst of a stylesheet, or javascript, I am not worried about those things much! When I find myself that I need to output userinput in the js area or stylesheet, I won't use this function. But I'm still interested in your comments as to how to deal with those context too.  But again, I'm *mostly* worried about the common stuff that is html and form objects.

The bottom line question is by forcing the utf8 and ent_quotes , am I safe?

Comment: Shouldn’t you have a Javascript tag here?

Comment: @tchrist I'm not sure what do you mean by "here"?

Answer (score 0):

Does htmlentities escape '. If so it should be mostly ok. There is always the problem of javascript: urls which you need to handle. And also remember that html attributes like onclick are actually javascript so your function will have no effect there. You will have to do js escaping. See the OWASP xss prevention cheat sheet. Regarding CSS, avoid putting user data there if you can. It requires a whitelist based key value validation approach.